# Создать класс, реализующий Эллипс

Tags: c#, классы, get, set, деструктор

Нужно создать класс, реализующий Эллипс. Объявление полей класса должно исчерпывающе характеризовать объект. Класс должен содержать конструктор, деструктор, Set- и Get- методы для каждого поля. В основной программе должен конструироваться один объект класса. В класс добавить метод вычисления площади или объема.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну как что уточнить? Вы открывали учебник, знаете как объявить класс в C#? Как написать метод и так далее. В том числе - по какой мат. формуле вычисляется площадь эллипса. Пока звучит как "Ничего не знаю, ничего не читал - напишите готовый код", это вы сайтом ошиблись.

Comment: @AK, а как вычислить объем эллипса?

Comment: Дело ясное, что дело темное. Вам бы почитать о том, из чего состоит эта задача.